# 2 differen't menus and it's using same items in both

Tags: theme-development, menus

I'm building a theme, in which, I have 2 menus:

1. Footer menu (`footer-menu`)
2. Main menu (`main-menu`)

However, when I called the main one in the `header.php` file it uses the same links added in the footer navigation.

Please see my code.

**Registering the navs**

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'main-menu' => esc_html__( 'Main', 'wd' ),
        'footer-menu' => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'wd' ),
    ) );
```

**header.php**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('main-menu'); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('footer-menu'); ?>
```

**What am I doing wrong? This has never occured before. Ever.**

Comment: Did you assign the menus in Menus > Manage Locations ? If no menu is selected for this menu position it reverts to the default menu. So on this page both dropdowns need to be 'filled'.

Comment: I did indeed. Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just the fact that they have the same name doesn't mean that WP knows the menu "main-menu" goes in the location "main-menu". You will have to specify this, as you can see from the source code of [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/):

```
$args = array (
  'menu'           => 'main-menu',
  'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
  );
wp_nav_menu ($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_nav_menu` expects an array of arguments, not a string. If `main-menu` and `footer-menu` are theme locations, then you need to specify that in your arguments:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );
```